# which API to use to edit alfresco docs in browser

Tags: java, alfresco, document, editing

I'm working on an app where we use alfresco public java API to manage documents.
We are already able to do basic operations such as create, delete, copy, upload etc. Now we are thinking about a way to display and edit .doc, .docx, .xls etc. files in a browser just like Alfresco share does.

I've been thinking about google Drive APIs but it seems it's just for interaction with documents stored on google drive. Nevertheless we store our documents with the alfresco repository system as explained [here](http://docs.alfresco.com/community/concepts/dev-repository-concepts.html).

Does anyone have an idea on which API we could use to do the job?